# A variable after a class name in PHP

Tags: php

```
class ClassNameOne (AnotherClassName $one_variable) {  
    //function task  
}
```

Can you explain me how this work? Why we use like that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: This will cause an error if the argument isn't a member of `AnotherClassName`

Comment: Where do you have this syntax from?

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is incorrect. It should look like this:

```
class ClassNameOne {
    public function __construct(AnotherClassName $one_variable){
        //function task
    }
}
```

The class name is given before the variable to specify the type of variable that will be passed to that function. So `$one_variable` must be an instance of the class `AnotherClassName` or it will throw an error.

Comment: Ah. I got it. Thank You.